# Android Mockito how to mock a resource

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric

I am using robolectric as my test runner with Mockito. I would like to know in Android how do i mock a resource. I have a array resource but in my test i'd like to mock the value.

i have an array that looks like this:

```
 <array name="screen_sections">
        <item>screen1</item>
        <item>screen2</item>
        <item>screen3</item>
        <item>screen4</item>
    </array>
```

and in test code i'd like to mock these values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do this using `Mockito.when`.  So I would create a normal array and save it with my values, something like this works good:

```
CharSequence myNewArray = {"value1","value2","value3"}
Mockito.when(resources.getTextArray(someID)).thenReturn(myNewArray);
```

Comment: how to create Resource object in test class? I've used MockResources class but giving me null values.